# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.omnifaces.util.selectitems.SelectItemsCollector.collectFromParent

Tags: jsf, converters, selectonemenu, omnifaces

I'm implementing a JSF project with the following:

- Wildfly 9.0.2
- Myfaces 2.2.9
- Primefaces 5.2
- Omnifaces 2.2

I want to implement `omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter` on all the custom entities of my project, I already followed the guide in http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter.

The problem is that when I select an option on my selectOneMenu the converter gets called 3 times the first time is called with the value selected the rest of the times with null so at the end a NullPointerException and is thrown the stack trace is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.omnifaces.util.selectitems.SelectItemsCollector.collectFromParent(SelectItemsCollector.java:109)
    at org.omnifaces.util.selectitems.SelectItemsUtils.findValueByStringConversion(SelectItemsUtils.java:50)
    at org.omnifaces.converter.SelectItemsConverter.getAsObject(SelectItemsConverter.java:95)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.RendererUtils.getConvertedUISelectOneValue(RendererUtils.java:989)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlMenuRendererBase.getConvertedValue(HtmlMenuRendererBase.java:153)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:662)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:598)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:274)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:788)
    at org.apache.myfaces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:213)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1019)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.visitTree(UIComponentBase.java:1191)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1047)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.visitTree(UIComponentBase.java:1191)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1047)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.visitTree(UIComponentBase.java:1191)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1047)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.visitTree(UIComponentBase.java:1191)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1047)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.visitTree(UIComponentBase.java:1191)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1047)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.visitTree(UIComponentBase.java:1191)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1047)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.visitTree(UIComponentBase.java:1191)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UITabPanel.visitTree(UITabPanel.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:345)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1047)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.visitTree(UIComponentBase.java:1191)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1047)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.visitTree(UIComponentBase.java:1191)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartialExecute(PartialViewContextImpl.java:430)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:411)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:85)
    at org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContext.processPartial(OmniPartialViewContext.java:136)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot$ProcessValidatorPhaseProcessor.process(UIViewRoot.java:1797)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1655)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:909)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsExecutor.execute(ProcessValidationsExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:196)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:143)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:198)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My problem is I can't find the failure since the exception is thrown outside my code, the relevant part of my code is:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="entity"
        value="#{backingBean.parentEntity.entity}"
        required="#{not empty param[save.clientId] or not empty param[anotherAction.clientId]}"
        converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"
        label="Entity">
    <p:ajax listener="#{backingBean.onEntityChanged}"
        onstart="$( '#parentForm\\:accordionPanel\\:data' ).addClass('loadinggif');"
        oncomplete="$( '#parentForm\\:accordionPanel\\:data' ).removeClass('loadinggif');"
        update="segment :parentForm:growl :solicitud:guardar :parentForm:accordionPanel:consultantInformation :parentForm:accordionPanel:data"
        process="entity segment :parentForm:accordionPanel:consultantInformation :parentForm:accordionPanel:data"
        global="false" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select ..." noSelectionOption="true"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{backingBean.entities}" var="entity" itemLabel="#{entity.nombre}" itemValue="#{entity}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

And in my Backing bean and custom objects:

```
public class BackingBean implements Serializable {
    private ParentObject parentEntity;
    private List<Entity> entities;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.parentEntity = new ParentObject();
        user = (UserDTO) SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                    .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    }

    /**
     * This method get called by a 
     * <f:metadata>
     *  <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{backingBean.parentObject.id}" />
     *  <f:viewAction action="#{backingBean.loadObject}" />
     * </f:metadata>
     */
    public void loadObject() {
        inicializarListas();
    }

    public void initializeLists() {
        entities = user.getEntities();
            if (entities == null || entities.isEmpty()) {
                entities = someController.findEntities();
            }
    }

    //getter and setter for parentEntity  
}
```

Any ideas

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I was working yesterday on the problem and noticed the typo but even fixing it the converter is getting the correct value the first time is called and null values the rest of the times.

Comment: How do you verify that the converter is invoked thrice? Try by removing the unwanted mess from `onstart`, `oncomplete`, `update` and `process` attributes of `<p:ajax>` enclosed within `<h:selectOneMenu>`. Moreover, use `<f:ajax>` with standard JSF components like `<h:selectOneMenu>` or if you were to insist upon using `<p:ajax>` anyway, then change `<h:selectOneMenu>` to `<p:selectOneMenu>` instead.

Comment: I debug the app, put a breakpoint in the [SelectItemsConverter.java](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.2/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/converter/SelectItemsConverter.java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is three-fold.

1. That confusing NPE from `SelectItemsCollector.java:109` is thrown while an exception should be thrown:

   ```
   106     } else {
   107
   108         // A value binding was specified, but of a type we don't support.
   109         throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(ERROR_UNKNOWN_SELECT_TYPE, value.getClass().toString()));
   110     }
   ```

   So, `value` is null where code didn't expect that. This is indeed a bug in OmniFaces. I just [fixed](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/4d442673371c4195d566ff8a4ddf2a270a7cee16) it for 2.3.

   ---
2. In Mojarra, this code is in first place never reached when `value` is `null`, but in Myfaces as in your case (and in RichFaces, as reported in OmniFaces [issue 185](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/185)) it unexpectedly is. It is what it is. Once you upgrade to OmniFaces 2.3 (currently only available as SNAPSHOT), world should be well again.

   ---
3. The select items `value` is `null`, because you typo'ed the managed bean name in the `value`.

   ```
   <f:selectItems value="#{bakingBean.entities}" ... />
   ```

   It's a bean, not a cake.

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer, I was working yesterday and I noticed the typo but after fixing it I still get the null values in the converter I have no idea what is causing this behavior. I will test versión 2.3 and will report back.

Comment: It works with snapshot 2.3 but I'm wondering when this version will be stable?

Comment: I guess we will release when I'm 100% satisfied with o:socket.